# how to do complex transactions in databases?

Tags: mysql, sql, transactions

How can I do an online transaction when two people are ordering an item at same time(same second) and the product quantity is only one, how should I do transaction. Consider I am using Python and MySQL(not necessarily answer generally otherwise)?

I am not expecting any source code here just wnat to know techniques thanks.

Comment: Databases enforce ACID (unless set up to not do so).  So, one person should see the product and the other should see no products.

Comment: but sir ,at the product page evertime i will query for `select * from products where available>0;`

Comment: this way i will show product to any number of people at same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do a SELECT before UPDATE in same transaction at the moment user try to buy something. So that your second user would get an info that there is no item he's looking for, because first user take it, and UPDATE wouldn't be runned.

Comment: thanks Alex, i had one more doubt asked one of my senior in interview that, how will we handle if both the users are buying in same fraction of second? Which user should get the product and how will he get can you help on this question too?

Comment: Well, you have to leave that job to db you're using, it would decide "who was first". Every db have a mechanism called Transaction Isolation, you could read more about this in wiki here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems).

Comment: This is so wrong, unless you lock the product when you do the `select`.  In fact, this approach is pretty much destined to lead to race conditions.

Comment: It depends on transaction isolation level. But you are right Gordon, locks would also solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I think you cant stop any one from seeing the same item but if someone purchased it or clicked on it u can update one column with trnid+1 put trigger on table on update.you can compare the same while updating if it is same let him take the product else it is sold or not available.

Comment: i guess trigger on item purchase will do

Comment: i had one more doubt asked one of my senior in interview that, how will we handle if both the users are buying in same fraction of second? Which user should get the product and how will he get can you help on this question too?

Comment: @PrabhakarJha whoever is buying it first as if both of them came in fraction of second but let them click on buy or whatever flow you decide just take the value of that column in some variable. lets assume it is 1 in table, both will have 1 after that someone will try to get that product by paying or ordering whatever you decide then update it to 2 as it is matching with 1st users value.2nd will still have 1 and try to update it but it is diff so on trigger while updating u can show product already sold.even if they are buying in fraction of second both cant update at same time.